# Find values that occur is multiple lists and their frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists. Each list has string values in it.
A value in the list is often seen passing through different lists. I want to find the values that occur in different lists at least more than k times.
For example, `127-0-0-1-59928` can be seen 3 times or `3-7-3-final-0` can be seen 4 times in the following case, and similarly there are other values that repeat.

```
[['127-0-0-1-59924'],
 ['127-0-0-1-59922'],
 ['127-0-0-1-59926'],
 ['127-0-0-1-59926', '3-8-0', '4-15-0-76', '3-7-3-final-0'],
 ['127-0-0-1-59928'],
 ['127-0-0-1-59928', '3-8-0', '4-15-0-76', '3-7-3-final-0'],
 ['127-0-0-1-59928'],
 ['127-0-0-1-59926'],
 ['127-0-0-1-34426'],
 ['127-0-0-1-34426', '3-8-0', '4-15-0-76', '3-7-3-final-0'],
 ['127-0-0-1-34428'],
 ['127-0-0-1-34428', '3-8-0', '4-15-0-76', '3-7-3-final-0'],
 ['127-0-0-1-34428'],
 ['127-0-0-1-34426']]
```

Is there an efficient way in which the frequencies of the values and/or values that occur in multiple lists more frequently (say above a certain threshold 'k') can be calculated?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: If the items cannot repeat inside a sub-list you can use [numpy unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html). It does more than you are asking but still...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just create a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with the elements of all the lists:

```
lst = [['127-0-0-1-59924'], ...]
import collections
counts = collections.Counter(c for l in lst for c in l)
print(counts.most_common())
# [('3-8-0', 4), ('4-15-0-76', 4), ('3-7-3-final-0', 4), ('127-0-0-1-59926', 3), ('127-0-0-1-59928', 3), ('127-0-0-1-34426', 3), ('127-0-0-1-34428', 3), ('127-0-0-1-59924', 1), ('127-0-0-1-59922', 1)]
```

Note that this will be the accumulated counts of all the lists, so if an element appears twice in *the same* list, that counts as two occurrences, too.
If, instead, you do not want to consider multiple occurrences in the same list, but just count the number of different lists the elements appear in, you could do the same, but convert the sublists to `set` first (the result is the same in this case):

```
counts = collections.Counter(c for l in lst for c in set(l))
```

Neither of those methods considers the position of the element in the list, in case that's a concern.

Comment: And the important thing to note here is that the input to `Counter` is a generator, so that it is not having to construct a flattened list.